# Access Attributes of a "related" model from the first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails application that has several models. One particular model is the "focus" of the application, and it has several one to many, and several many to many relationships defined.

I have created logic to export the fields to a CSV file, and within the model I have defined a couple methods someone showed me to facilitate this. Here are the two methods:

```
  def self.csv_header 
    fields = attr_order.*.to_s & content_columns.*.name 
    fields -= %w{created_at updated_at created_on updated_on deleted_at} 
    fields.reject! { |f| never_show? f } 
    fields 
  end 

  def to_csv 
    self.class.csv_header.map { |h| send(h) } 
  end
```

However, in my primary model (called patient) I need to include fields from some of the other one-to-many models (e.g. home_address, which contains street, city, state, zip, etc.). Is this possible to keep inside the patient model? I have set up logic in my controller which can add the other model's information, but it seems like it would be much cleaner to let the patient model grab all the additional information it needs from the other models and add it to the export rows.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your work should be done in the models anyways, in my opinion. Keep the controllers thin, and the models fat, vs the other way around.

If you need to then access some attributes - say `Patient` has a 1-to-1 relationship with `Address`, then feel free to do so! Just do something like the data something like:

```
fields += HomeAddress.csv_header
```

home_address.rb

```
def self.csv_header
    ... pretty much the same thing as Patient.csv_header
end
```

So, you're not *keeping* the data in the Patient model, but rather, you're keeping the data where it belongs and just being able to access it.

Comment: OK, that's awesome, and I think I'm almost there. I wasn't using the proper class name for the reference when I tried that before, so thanks a ton for that. However, when I put in your code (and update the corresponding csv_header code in the referenced model), I'm getting an error that the HomeAddress fields aren't in my main class. Is there a way for me to update that to where it will prefix those field names with the class name (like HomeAddress.street_address1) instead of just the field name alone?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, within `HomeAddress.csv_header`, you could do (at the end): `fields = fields.collect{ |f| "HomeAddress." + f }`

Comment: Argh! No, good suggestion, but I'm still getting "undefined method 'HomeAddress.city' for #<Patient..." or whatever happens to be first in the list. I also tried home_address (relationship name defined in Patients), @home_address, and none of the three worked. Is it possible that .map just won't work with a relationship?